# Error 121 - Duplicate key on write or update

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Continue to get this error in MariaDB 10.3.13/14/15/16 even though the table doesn't exist and the FK doesn't display in the system schema.  I have read many of the posts regarding this error and am aware that the FK name cannot exist anywhere else in the DB, which it does not.  This issue does not occur in 10.3.12, so I am beginning to wonder if this is a problem with MariaDB?  I cannot believe the answer should be, "drop you database and start over", as there should be some way to get Maria to see that the FK does not exist.

Dropped the table completely and verified that the FK in question only exists in this table that was dropped.

I can get the table rebuilt by removing the declaration for the FK constraint from the create table statement and once the table rebuilds, the FK is there, like it somehow picked it up from still existing in the DB somewhere - crazy.

My create statement is shown below

```
CREATE TABLE `trace_properties` (
  `MessageId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PropertyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PropertyValue` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`MessageId`,`PropertyName`),
  KEY `NameValueIDX` (`PropertyName`,`PropertyValue`(767)),
  KEY `MessageIdIDX` (`MessageId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_traceproperties_1` FOREIGN KEY (`MessageId`) REFERENCES `trace_messages` (`TraceMessageId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My expected results is that I should be able to drop trace_properties, which does happen successfully, and then perform a create using the script above, which fails 100% of the time indicating that the FK exists.

However, I can run the following query and get an empty result set, indicating that FK doesn't exist, at least in the information schema.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
AND information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'idf';
```

Comment: I have found that if you first drop the constraint, then save the table, then drop the table, then re-build the table, it works.  However, this seems very broke to me.  Why is MariaDB failing to fully/completely remove the FK constraint during the table drop?  Am I missing something here?  Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: File a bug at jira.mariadb.org .